# JavaScript FormData POST request. How am I supposed to send json part with Content-Type: application/json, but without filename?

Tags: javascript, typescript, http-post

I am trying to create such FormData request:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename="22611.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="complaint"
Content-Type: application/json

[{"someKey":"3285577","someAnotherKey":1}]
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachments"; filename="22039.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

(data)
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

As you can see, it contains 2 images marked as `attachements` and one part called `complaint`.

**I tried to use this code:**

```
files.forEach(file => formData.append('attachments', file));
formData.append('complaint', new Blob([JSON.stringify(complaints)], {
  type: 'application/json
}));`
```

But it also adds `filename` part, which makes it to look like below (which is not what I want). I can send empty `filename`, but it is still included in request anyway.

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="complaint"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: application/json

[{"someKey":"3285577","someAnotherKey":1}]
-----------------------------223573272824043770992215051292--
```

**I also tried to use this code:**

```
files.forEach(file => formData.append('attachments', file));
formData.append('complaint', JSON.stringify(complaints));
```

But that way I am not able to set any `Content-Type` value:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="complaint"

[{"someKey":"3285577","someAnotherKey":1}]
-----------------------------3285194322809168152615032804--
```

How am I supposed to create this FormData which satisfies API?

Comment: Ignore the file name on the server side, its easier!